# Strange serialization in the WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have some problem with WCF service on C#.

I try to define little service:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace TestApp
{
    [ServiceContractAttribute(Namespace = "http://testApp.ru/LittleService", Name = "ILittleService", ConfigurationName = "ILittleService")]
    public interface ILittleService
    {
        [OperationContract(Action = "urn:GetArrayOfCars")]
        [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
        [XmlSerializerFormat]
        GetArrayOfCarsResponse GetArrayOfCars(GetArrayOfCarsRequest request);

        [OperationContract(Action = "urn:GetArrayOfTrains")]
        [TransactionFlow(TransactionFlowOption.Allowed)]
        [XmlSerializerFormat]
        GetArrayOfTrainsResponse GetArrayOfTrains(GetArrayOfTrainsRequest request);
    }
}
```

There are array of cars/trains named as result in each response:

```
namespace TestApp.ResponseWrappers
{
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "GetArrayOfCarsResponse", WrapperNamespace = "http://testApp.ru/LittleService", IsWrapped = true)]
    public class GetArrayOfCarsResponse
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "", Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute()]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public CarResult[] result { get; set; }

        public GetArrayOfCarsResponse()
        {
        }

        public GetArrayOfCarsResponse(CarResult[] result)
        {
            this.result = result;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
namespace TestApp.ResponseWrappers
{
    [System.ServiceModel.MessageContractAttribute(WrapperName = "GetArrayOfTrainsResponse", WrapperNamespace = "http://testApp.ru/LittleService", IsWrapped = true)]
    public class GetArrayOfTrainsResponse
    {

        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace = "", Order = 0)]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute()]
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
        public TrainResult[] result { get; set; }

        public GetArrayOfTrainsResponse()
        {
        }

        public GetArrayOfTrainsResponse(TrainResult[] result)
        {
            this.result = result;
        }
    }
}
```

And when I try to use this service via SoupUI:

GetArrayOfCars method works fine

For GetArrayOfTrains method I got a strange error:

```
Wed Sep 13 14:45:23 GMT+03:00 2017:ERROR:org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://jcaps2-kv:8080 refused
   org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://jcaps2-kv:8080 refused
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:290)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:561)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport$Helper.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:233)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.HttpClientSupport.execute(HttpClientSupport.java:323)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.submitRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:297)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.submit.transports.http.HttpClientRequestTransport.sendRequest(HttpClientRequestTransport.java:227)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlSubmit.run(WsdlSubmit.java:119)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:123)
    at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.http.SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:273)
    ... 16 more
```

But service methods works fine (I debug they). Error detecting (via SvcTraceViewer) on result serialization stage:

```
Massage: Unable to cast object of type 'TestApp.Data.TrainResult[]' to type 'TestApp.Data.CarResult[]'.
StackTrace: Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriterIProductCatalogV2Part1.Write89_GetRegionalCatalogInfoResponse(Object[] p)
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
```

After study of the issue, I get WSDL of service and found in it very interesting rows:

```
<xs:complexType name="ArrayOfCarResult">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" form="unqualified" name="CarResult" nillable="true" type="CarResult"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="result" type="ArrayOfCarResult"/>

<xs:element name="GetArrayOfCarsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="result"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="GetArrayOfTrainsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" ref="result"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

If I use different names to arrays in responses all methods works fine. But I need to use the simular names.

Using ElementName property for XmlArrayAttribute does not help me (if I use "result" string).

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

Comment: Try renaming your 'result' properties to carResult and trainResult.

Comment: I already tried it, and all works fine (I wrote about it in original post). But I need to use simular names.

Comment: I think I'm missing something here. Like the definitions for CarResult and TrainResult. Also, is that WSDL auto-generated?

Comment: It does not metter what definiton of CarResult and TrainResult. They can by empty classes or have few fields.
Yes - WSDL is auto-generated, and I cited it here for the possibility of a deeper analysis.

Comment: Well the clue is in the WSDL as it clearly states that GetArrayOfCarsResponse and GetArrayOfTrainsResponse contain an element called 'result' which is of type ArrayOfCarResult which consists of a list of CarResults. Hence the type mismatch. Could you post your Service Contract?